# android app wrote to get place name of id 2 php gives null

Tags: php, android

I was trying out this code but it gives null. where it should be giving me the place name. what seems to be the problem in my code? i want to get place details by giving the place ID. But i debugged too, it was always returning null

**Code**

```
String result = "";
                InputStream is = null;
                // the year data to send
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place_id", "2"));

                // http post
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://example.com/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }
                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // parse json data
                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        TextView z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        z.setText(json_data.getString("place_id"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
            }

        });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "db_config.php";

$q=mysql_query("SELECT 'name' FROM places WHERE place_id='".$_REQUEST['place_id']."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too less information to help. Are you sure your PHP script returns anything? What logging of http response shows? Maybe it is all fine with your code and null is what you should get as problem lurks elsewhere?

BTW: your PHP code is very bad. You are open to exploitation with SQL Injection and in general you should always check if query (or fopen or anything) succeeded before you try to consume expected data it should return, as there is NO guarantee all went fine. Habit of error checking is crucial to solid software development. I also recomment to not use "?>" if it is just pure PHP script file, not mixed with HTML or anything (mixing is bad too).

Comment: can you please tell me how.. im really new... im trying to learn by this. thankyou

Comment: Not sure to what part your "how" applies, but: add `Log.i(TAG, response);` after your `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);` then check LogCat to see what your response really holds (you can also set breakpoint and peek the variable, but logging is fine). Launch your PHP script and see what it prints out. Then update your question with these information so we could see it too. As for SQL Injection: never use data unprocessed in your queries. Validate and escape it first (see `mysql_real_escape_string()`). And if place_id is `INT`, remove quotes.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE ANSWER

```
ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String result = "";
                InputStream is = null;

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place_id", "3"));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://hopscriber.com/test.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }
                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // parse json data
                String version = null;
                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        version = json_data.getString("name");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), version,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        TextView x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        x.setText(version);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), version, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

php

```
<?php

include "db_config.php";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[place_id])."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

thanx all for the help